# How does rust deal with the ownership of the returned string?

Tags: rust

This is the code I have:

```
fn test_function() -> String {
    String::from("")
}

fn main() {
    test_function();
    println!("Hello");
}
```

I was expecting rust to complain about test_function return value not being assigned, but it just works.

How are the rules of ownership applied here?

Comment: How is that related to ownership? Return value not used is at most a warning.

Comment: I though it was going to complain just for clarity. As a beginner ownership is something that I just learned in rust and this situation is something a bit uncertain. I knew what was hapenning, but was a bit weird to do not have a variable receiving the ownership of the returned string. It is a bit hard for me to think that the main function was the new owner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was expeting rust to complain about test_function return value not being assigned, but it just works.

Why would it complain? Rust's type system is affine, meaning values can be used *at most* once. Using them 0 times is valid (you can mark types and functions as `#[must_use]` to trigger a warning, but even then a simple `let _ = ...` will silence it)

> How are the rules of ownership applied here?

The string is moved out of the function, then dropped by the caller since nothing is keeping it alive.

Comment: I though it was going to complain just for clarity. As a beginner ownership is something that I just learned in rust and this situation is something a bit uncertain. I knew what was hapenning, but was a bit weird to do not have a variable receiving the ownership of the returned string. It is a bit hard for me to think that the main function was the new owner.

Answer (score 3):

Without optimizations, the return value of
`fn test_function()`
Is just immediately dropped, and it's memory freed.

Since it its ownership is relinquished.
Before none-lexical-lifetimes it would have been freed at the end of `fn main()`

Comment: I don't think that final comment about NLL is correct. Even without NLL temporary values like this return value had different drop timing.

Answer (score 0):

Ownership is passed to the `main` function, which drops it when returning. The fact that the value is unassigned does not matter.